# Creating a basic collage plugin with jquery, js or HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a collage plugin which will allow users to add images from my site and in a pop-up window, allow them to make collages, drag them around and create layers etc.

I'm fine with jquery and javascript, if anyone is able to give me a few pointers on where to start or information I'd be really grateful.

Btw, I have Googled this extensively and yes I have seen these plugins:

http://radikalfx.com/files/collage/demo.html
http://www.lesterflor.com/HTML5/CanvasExample/index2.html

But these ones don't explain how they did it. Any sort of documentation or other suggestions for other methods is really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: `these ones don't explain how they did it` Read source code?

Comment: yes, very helpful indeed.. Reading the source code, especially minified js, often doesn't explain the whole process involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the outline of a drag/drop collage for you to work on:

- Add a div for users to drag/drop their images onto.
- Add dragenter, dragover & drop event handlers to that div
- In the drop event, use `FileReader` & `.readAsDataURL` to get the dataURL of the dropped image(s).
- Create image objects of each dataURL using `new Image()`
- Draw the image objects to the canvas using 'context.drawImage'
- Style the canvas drawing as you desire.

Good luck with your collage!